# AngularJS Get text selection and append html to start and end of selection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Have little dilemma here. I'm building text editor in angular js. The problem that I have is, when user selects part of text within a paragraph or heading I need to change styling of that part of text to bold / italic etc.

So basically I need to wrap selected text in `<strong></strong>` or `<em></em>`.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V0FiUPW8VhB06jJWAde7)

I have a directive

```
editorApp.directive('watchSelection', function() {
   return function(scope, elem) {
       elem.on('mouseup', function() {
           scope.startPosition = elem[0].selectionStart;
           scope.endPosition = elem[0].selectionEnd;
           //    scope.selected = elem[0].value.substring(start, end);
           scope.$apply();
       });
   };
});
```

That gets text selection its startposition and endposition. On button click I need to wrap that selection in specific tags, which I'm hoping to accomplish with this function:

```
$scope.boldText = function(startPosition, endPosition) {
        $scope.start = startPosition;
        $scope.end = endPosition;
        var htmlStart = angular.element('<strong>');
        var htmlEnd = angular.element('</strong>');

        $scope.start.append(htmlStart);
        $scope.end.append(htmlEnd);
    };
```

I relatively new to angular and I might have taken a bigger bite than I can handle :)

Issue is I can't get selection to wrap inside them tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to watch anything.

```
$scope.boldText = function() {
    document.execCommand('bold');
};
```

This will bold the selected text.

Comment: Legend! Never knew this existed.